# JPanel: how to add buttons above table?

Tags: java, swing

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    bigbutton = new JButton("Big Button");
    clearbutton = new JButton("Clear Page");
    resetbutton = new JButton("Start Over");
    finishbutton = new JButton("Finish");


    panel.add(sometable);
    return panel;
```

right now what happens is they sprawl horizontally. I want the four buttons horizontally and above the table.

Comment: Going to need more code than that to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> right now what happens is they sprawl horizontally.

In addition to @tulskiy's and @Andrew Thompson's suggestions, it may be useful to note that the default layout of [`JPanel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) is [`FlowLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#flow), which arranges components in a horizontal row.

Addendum:

> change `JPanel`'s `FlowLayout` to `BorderLayout` or some other layout?

Choosing a layout is partly a matter of taste, but I'd combine the suggested approaches, as shown in [*How to Use Tool Bars*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#flow). Note how `ToolBarDemo` extends `JPanel` and then invokes the superclass constructor to specify `BorderLayout()`:

```
public class ToolBarDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    ...
    public ToolBarDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        ...
        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar("Still draggable");
        addButtons(toolBar);
        ...
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 130));
        add(toolBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(sometable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    ...
}
```

Absent extension, just use the constructor directly:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

Alternative, use the `setLayout()` method inherited by `JPanel`.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Comment: anyway to change Jpanel's FlowLayout to borderlayout or some other layout ?

Answer (score 2):

Set you panel's layout to BorderLayout, add your buttons to a box, add the box to your panel with BorderLayout.PAGE_START constraint, add your table with Borderlayout.CENTER constraint.

Comment: The OP might also consider adding the JButtons to a JToolBar instead of the 'box'.